# numpy mask using np.where then replace values

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got two 2-D numpy arrays with same shape, let's say (10,6).

The first array `x` is full of some meaningful float numbers.

```
x = np.arange(60).reshape(-1,6)
```

The second array `a` is sparse array, with each row contains ONLY 2 non-zero values.

```
a = np.zeros((10,6))
for i in range(10):
    a[i, 1] = 1
    a[i, 2] = 1
```

Then there's a third array with the shape of (10,2), and I want to update the values of each row to the first array `x` at the position where `a` is not zero.

```
v = np.arange(20).reshape(10,2)
```

so the original `x` and the updated `x` will be:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11],
   [12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17],
   [18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23],
   [24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
   [30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35],
   [36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
   [42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47],
   [48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53],
   [54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59]])
```

and

```
array([[ 0,  0,  1,  3,  4,  5],
   [ 6,  2,  3,  9, 10, 11],
   [12,  4,  5, 15, 16, 17],
   [18,  6,  7, 21, 22, 23],
   [24,  8,  9, 27, 28, 29],
   [30, 10, 11, 33, 34, 35],
   [36, 12, 13, 39, 40, 41],
   [42, 14, 15, 45, 46, 47],
   [48, 16, 17, 51, 52, 53],
   [54, 18, 19, 57, 58, 59]])
```

I've tried the following method

```
x[np.where(a!=0)] = v
```

Then I got an error of `shape mismatch: value array of shape (10,2) could not be broadcast to indexing result of shape (20,)`

What's wrong with this approach, is there an alternative to do it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: So, each row of `a` would have exactly two nonzeros?

Comment: Also, would those nonzeros in `a` always be adjacent (next to each other)?

Comment: What if you assign with : `x[a!=0] = v.ravel()`?

Comment: yeah exactly two nonzeros, and the position of the nonzeros in each row may vary

Comment: Yeah that works! Could you write it in the answer so that I can mark it as a solution?

Comment: That's really trivial based on the [boolean-indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing). I would encourage you to research and post your own answer on this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comment by @Divakar, the problem happens because the shapes of the two variables on both side of the assignment mark `=` are different.

To the left, the expression `x[np.where(a!=0)]` or `x[a!=0]` or `x[np.nonzero(a)]` are not structured, which has a shape of `(20,)`

To the right, we need an array of similar shape to finish the assignment. Therefore, a simple `ravel()` or `reshape(-1)` will do the job.

so the solution is as simple as `x[a!=0] = v.ravel()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

arrayOne = np.random.rand(6).reshape((2, 3))
arrayTwo = np.asarray([[0,1,2], [1,2,0]])
arrayThree = np.zeros((2, 2))

arrayOne[arrayTwo != 0] = arrayThree.ravel()
print(arrayOne)

[[0.56251284 0.         0.        ]
 [0.         0.         0.20076913]]
```

Note regarding edit: The solution above is not mine, all credit goes to Divakar. I edited because my earlier answer misunderstood OP's question and I wish to avoid confusion.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I think what I wanted is the opposite: assign the value of arrayThree to arrayOne